# Got Numerical result out of range and Invalid argument on sysctl

Tags: sysctl

On one operating system, when i execute the following sysctl command,

got errors:

sysctl -w kernel.sem="4096 2097152000 2097152 512000"

--> sysctl: setting key "kernel.sem": Numeric result out of range.

systcl -w kernel.shmmni=819200

--> sysctl: setting key "kernel.shmmni": Invalid argument.

And i guess the some value is too large.

When i reduce the value, there is no errors.

But the same command on another operating system got no errors.

So at my point, there maybe some check rule,

and the max value of the key between the two operating system is different.

So my doubt is where is the max value stored on the operating system?

Comment: Used strace to diagnose, got nothing.